# Not assignable dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Simple question. Why is something like this not possible?

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Func<MarketModel, string>, Func<Market, string>>
        MarketMappingDictionary = new Dictionary<Func<MarketModel, string>, Func<Market, string>>
        {
            {o => o.Name, o => o.Name},
            {o => o.CountryId, o => o.Country.Code},
            {o => o.CurrencyId, o => o.Currency.Code},
        };

private static readonly Dictionary<Func<ParnerModel, string>, Func<Pertner, string>>
       PartnerMappingDictionary = .....


private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Func<object, string>, Func<object, string>>> 
        _objectMappingDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Func<object, string>, Func<object, string>>>
    {
        {typeof (MarketModel), MarketMappingDictionary},
        {typeof (PartnerModel), PartnerMappingDictionary}

};
```

Error message says that `Dictionary<Func<MarketModel, string>, Func<Market, string>>`
 is not assignable with `Dictionary<Func<object, string>, Func<object, string>>`

Comment: @JonathanCamilleri: Could you elaborate, please? The question you linked to is about dictionaries with a read-only interface/dictionaries that do not allow modifying operations. How is that connected to the assignment problem presented here?

Comment: Jan, could you post some more complete code? Or at least the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Misread the question, deleted bad comment

Comment: How are the dictionaries actually going to be used here? If they are read-only, it's possible you could get the code to compile by using variance-supporting types (`Func` already does, you'd also need `IReadOnlyDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`). If not, then answer you've received already explains why what you're trying to do is bad (i.e. the compiler error is protecting you from yourself :) ).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible because you can't cast a `Dictionary<Func<MarketModel, string>, Func<MarketModel, string>>` to a `Dictionary<Func<object, string>, Func<object, string>>`.

Those types aren't remotely compatible. If it were allowed, you could do this:

```
Func<object, string> f = o => o.ToString();

var d = new Dictionary<Func<MarketModel, string>, Func<MarketModel, string>>();

Dictionary<Func<object, string>, Func<object, string>> d2 = d;

d2[f] = f;
```

And now `d` would contain a value that is *not* a `Func<MarketModel, string>`. That would be a big problem.